# combined two arrays of different size with different properties

Tags: powershell

My goal is to get all group settings and add the total group member count for each group along with the total owners, managers for each group.

Either array can be larger or they can be equal.

I start with getting group member count.

```
$GroupMembersCount = gam print groups domain <domain.com> members managers owners countsonly | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Then I get the settings for each group

```
$GroupSettings = gam print groups settings | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Both arrays share the email property and nothing else.
The `$GroupMembersCount` is just a count for all the members and what right they have in each group.
looks like

```
email, manager, member
address.com, 1, 5
newaddress.com, 0,0
anotheraddress,3,3
etc...
```

the other array `$GroupSettings` has like 30 column headers and one header is email addresses and the other headers are a bunch of `true or false` depending on the setting for the group.

I want to combine both arrays into 1.

I know I need to do something like create a new array but the problem I have is how do I combine them since I do not know which will be larger?

```
$result = $null
$result = $GroupSettings + $GroupMembersCount | Select-Object -Unique
```

Above did not help

```
$Max = $null
$Max = ($GroupSettings.Count, $GroupMembersCount.count | Measure-Object -Maximum).Maximum

$resultsarray = $null
$resultsarray = For ($i = 0, $I -lt $max, $I++) {
do stuff
}
```

If I do something like above which array am I going to index through to get them all ?

The End result will tell me
Which setting each group has, its total members, its total managers and its total owners.

I need this so I can filter groups that have no owners and managers along with other key settings

Comment: "I want to combine both arrays into 1." - what would the resulting objects look like? Should they all have 100+ properties? Perhaps try explaining _why_ you want to combine them. What question are you trying to answer about these groups based on "combining both arrays"?

Comment: Not at all. I still don't know what you're trying to do with this data, or what you're interested in finding out

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I updated again.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a hashtable to "index" the first data set based on the email address:

```
$GroupMemberCount = gam print groups domain <domain.com> members managers owners countsonly | ConvertFrom-Csv
$GroupMemberCountByEmail = @{}
$GroupMemberCount |ForEach-Object {
    $GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email] = $_
}
```

Now we can use `Select-Object` to attach the relevant counts to each group setting object based on the `email` property:

```
$result = $GroupSettings |Select *,@{Name='MemberCount';Expression={[int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].member}},@{Name='ManagerCount';Expression={[int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].manager}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above explained the answer, here I am going to break down what I did and learned for anyone passing by with a similar problem.

What I did:

```
$GroupMembersCount = $null
$GroupMembersCount = gam print groups domain <domain.com> members managers owners countsonly | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupSettings = $null
$GroupSettings = gam print groups settings | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupMemberCountByEmail = @{}
$GroupMembersCount | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email] = $_
}

$GroupSettings | Select-Object *,
    @{
        Name = 'MembersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].MembersCount }
    },@{
        Name = 'ManagersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].ManagersCount }
    },@{
        Name = 'OwnersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].OwnersCount }
    } |
    Export-Csv 'c:\temp\groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

The above works. The first part, what [@Mathias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70610156/15339544) had me build, was a [*hash table*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2).

The beauty is in the `$result`, here, Mathias uses [*calculated properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2). One key point in the `$result` line is as follows:

```
@{
    Name = 'ManagersCount'
    Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].ManagersCount }
}
```

The tail of each calculated property, like `.managerscount` part has to be the value in the hash created above.

There is plenty here I don't understand but, if you are looking hopefully it will lead you like it did for me.

Comment: Do you mind if I edit your answer? One of the key points, for me personally and probably for most people, to give code readability is to use vertical coding style instead of horizontal.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon go for it. or add an answer and I will delete mine. One question I do not get is how are the Array combining.. how does it know email in one = email in other to make one answer?

Comment: Both arrays correlate on the `Email` property hence we can say that the arrays can be "joined" or "merged" by this property. The _keys_ of the Hashtable are the emails and the _Expression_ of the calculated properties are using the `Email` property to lookup on the other array (which is stored as _Values_ on the Hashtable).

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon so if an email address is in one not the other it will still appear in the final output?

Comment: There wouldn't be a correlation there, hence, on `$result`, the values for `MembersCount`, `ManagersCount` and `OwnerCount` would be `$null` for that email.