# How could I add an if statement when combining two different arrays

Tags: powershell

today I asked
[combined two arrays of different size with different properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609905/combined-two-arrays-of-different-size-with-different-properties/70610915?noredirect=1#comment124824384_70610915)

Here is the answer

```
$GroupMembersCount = $null
$GroupMembersCount = gam print groups domain <domain.com> members managers owners countsonly | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupSettings = $null
$GroupSettings = gam print groups settings | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupMemberCountByEmail = @{}
$GroupMembersCount | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email] = $_
}

$GroupSettings | Select-Object *,
    @{
        Name = 'MembersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].MembersCount }
    },@{
        Name = 'ManagersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].ManagersCount }
    },@{
        Name = 'OwnersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].OwnersCount }
    } |
    Export-Csv 'c:\temp\groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

How can I add a column to this answer above that will give me a True or false if all counts are zero ?

I think I need `if` before the export above but I am not sure how to `If (X -eq 0 -and Y -eq 0) { Do stuff }` here since I don't know how to address the X before the export.

```
| Export-Csv 'c:\temp\groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: You could just pipe into a second `Select-Object` -> `| Select-Object *,@{n='AllZeroes';e={-not ($_.MembersCount -or $_.ManagersCount -or $_.OwnersCount) }}`

Comment: @AdminOfThings thanks for your time. I have followed you for a long time. Make this an answer and I can close this. 
I need to learn calculated properties better.

Comment: If calculated properties give you a hard time you can stick to classic coding and use a `foreach` loop casting `pscustomobject` with all the combined properties, it is mostly doing the same thing as `Select-Object` and the performance implications are the same or it is likely the loop will be faster.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I had almost done it that way but kept getting confused because the arrays are different sizes and properties.

Comment: That's fine, in this particular case, instead of a `foreach` you would use a `for`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would just pipe to another `Select-Object` to keep your code cleaner. It is not required if you want to reuse your hash table lookups in another calculated property.

```
$GroupSettings | Select-Object *,
    @{
        Name = 'MembersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].MembersCount }
    },@{
        Name = 'ManagersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].ManagersCount }
    },@{
        Name = 'OwnersCount'
        Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].OwnersCount }
    } |
        Select-Object *,
            @{
                Name='AllZeroes'
                Expression={-not ($_.MembersCount -or $_.ManagersCount -or $_.OwnersCount) }
            } | 
                Export-Csv 'c:\temp\groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
```

`AllZeroes` property will return `$true` if all counts are `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Again I want to add what I did. Please note to any reader some of my answer is different because I use a tool called GAM to help me administrate Google. GAM forced me to pivot from what I accepted above.

PS: I find with most answers here there are adjustments needed. Your mileage may vary so tread carefully.

```
<#
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70613438/how-could-i-add-an-if-statement-when-combining-two-different-arrays/70614250#70614250

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70609905/combined-two-arrays-of-different-size-with-different-properties/70610915?noredirect=1#comment124824384_70610915
#>

$GroupMembersCount = $null
$GroupMembersCount = gam print groups domain <Domain.com> members managers owners countsonly | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupSettings = $null
$GroupSettings = gam print groups settings | ConvertFrom-Csv

$GroupsEmpty = $null
$GroupsEmpty = gam config csv_output_row_filter "directMembersCount:count=0" print groups directmemberscount | ConvertFrom-csv

$GroupMemberCountByEmail = @{}
$GroupMembersCount | ForEach-Object {
    $GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email] = $_
}

$Result = $null
$Result = $GroupSettings | Select-Object *,
@{
    Name       = 'MembersCount'
    Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].MembersCount }
}, @{
    Name       = 'ManagersCount'
    Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].ManagersCount }
}, @{
    Name       = 'OwnersCount'
    Expression = { [int]$GroupMemberCountByEmail[$_.email].OwnersCount }
}

If ($GroupsEmpty) {
    $Result | Add-Member -NotePropertyName EmptyGroup -NotePropertyValue $false
    
    function Get-ArrayRowIndex {
        param(
            [parameter(mandatory = $true)][array]$Property,
            [parameter(mandatory = $true)][string]$Value
        )

        [int]$index = 0
        while ($index -lt ($Property.count)) {
            if ($Property[$index] -eq $Value) {
                return [int]$index
            }
            $index++
        }
        return $null
    }

    $Result | ForEach-Object {
        If ($GroupsEmpty.email -contains $_.Email) {
            $UpdateRowIndex = $null
            #Get-ArrayRowIndex tries to find the item to update in the Result array. $UpdateRowIndex can't be [int]
            $UpdateRowIndex = Get-ArrayRowIndex -Property $($Result.email) -Value $_.Email
            #update the correct item in the array,changing flag made above.
            If ($null -ne $UpdateRowIndex) {
                $Result[$UpdateRowIndex].EmptyGroup = $true
            }
            Else {
                #If location in array was not found function Get-ArrayRowIndex.
                Write-Error "Problem with final report. Index location in the result array was not found using Get-ArrayRowIndex."
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
                break script
            }
        }
    } 
}

$result | Export-Csv 'c:\temp\groups.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8

Try {
    Invoke-Item -Path 'c:\temp\groups.csv'
}
Catch {
    write-error "Final report not found at c:\temp\groups.csv"
}
```

There are better ways to do what I did above but this suits me for now.